# compilation error while drawing regular polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf

I created tikset based on the following example [HERE](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/regular-polygons/) to draw regular polygon. But I've got compilation error and i'm unable to know why :/ .

In addition:

- the pentagon label doesn't appear, while the others are
- I've got crashs when I declare the node as in the example

  \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {120,240} {
              -- (\x:\R)
          } -- cycle (90:\R) node[above] {$n=3$} ;

[image]

**main.tex**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usepackage{adjustbox}% permet de déterminer une taille de fenêtre

%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans 
%                       \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)

\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

%\input{types/f2d_fig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{pics/triangloid_regular/.style={code={%
    \tikzset{triangloid_regular/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangloid_regular/##1}}%
    \draw[thick, pic actions] (-30:\pv{radius}) \foreach \x in {90,210}%
        {
            -- (\x:\pv{radius})}%
            -- cycle (90:\pv{radius})%
            (0,\pv{radius}) coordinate node[above, scale=2.5] {\pv{lab}}%
            ;
        }
    },
  triangloid_regular/.cd,
  radius/.initial=3cm,
  lab/.initial=,
  ;
}

\tikzset{pics/squaroid_regular/.style={code={%
    \tikzset{squaroid_regular/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/squaroid_regular/##1}}
    \draw[thick, pic actions] (45:\pv{radius}) \foreach \x in {135,225,...,359}
        {
            -- (\x:\pv{radius})}%
            -- cycle (90:\pv{radius})%
            (0,\pv{radius}) coordinate node[above, scale=2.5] {\pv{lab}}
            ;
        }
    },
  squaroid_regular/.cd,
  radius/.initial=3cm,
  lab/.initial=,
  ;
}

\tikzset{pics/pentagoid_regular/.style={code={%
    \tikzset{pentagoid_regular/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/squaroid_regular/##1}}
    \draw[thick, pic actions] (18:\pv{radius}) \foreach \x in {90,162,...,359}
        {
            -- (\x:\pv{radius})}%
            -- cycle (90:\pv{radius})%
            (0,\pv{radius}) coordinate node[above, scale=2.5] {\pv{lab}}
            ;
        }
    },
  pentagoid_regular/.cd,
  radius/.initial=3cm,
  lab/.initial=,
  ;
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Radius of regular polygons
\newdimen\R
\R=2cm

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\sansmath\sffamily},thick, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm]

% Indicate the boundary of the regular polygons
\pic {triangloid_regular={lab=Triangle}};
\pic[xshift=7cm] {squaroid_regular={lab=Square}};
\pic[yshift=-7cm] {pentagoid_regular={lab=Pentagone}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I guess it's business as usual, I'm missing a little detail, making me go around in cirle >-< .

Comment: You have a copy paste error -- you are referring to `squaroid` in your pentagon definition

Comment: thanks, I've just changed it.
for the rest, the problem remains

Comment: Isn't it in practical use of regular polygons simpler to use `tikz` library `shapes.geometric` and its shape `regular polygon`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems much easier to use polar coordinates. This way the code:

```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{xcolor}

  \tikzset{pics/polygon/.style 2 args={
      code = {
        \foreach \a [evaluate=\a as \an using (270+(\a+0.5)*360/#1)] in {1, ..., #1} {
              \draw(\an-360/#1:1)--(\an:1);
        }
        \node at (90:1.3){#2};
      }
    }
  }

  \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pic at (0,0) {polygon=3{Triangle}};
      \pic at (3,0) {polygon=4{Square}};
      \pic at (6,0) {polygon=5{Pentagon}};
      \pic at (9,0) {polygon=6{Hexagon}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

The only mildly tricky bit is working out the appropriate angles so that the "bottom" edge is horizontal as in the OP. It would be easy to add other features to control the size of the polygons, their `fill` etc etc. (The other option is to use `shape=regular polygon` from `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}`; see section 51.5.3 of the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual.)

**Edit**

As for the code in the OP, the problem seems to be that you are referring to `triangloid_regular` etc before they are defined. If you put the initial definitions a little higher up then the code compiles. The "Pentagone" (Pentagon?) did not appear because you have `squareoid`, instead of `pentagoid`, in the `\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{...}}` statement. A third, extremely minor point, is that I would not use names with an underscore as TeX tends not to like them. In this case they work, of course, so I am just being precious and you are more than welcome to ignore me:).

Here is the updated code from the OP with these changes, which now compiles.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usepackage{adjustbox}% permet de déterminer une taille de fenêtre

%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans
%                       \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)

\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

%\input{types/f2d_fig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{triangloid regular/.cd,
  radius/.initial=3cm,
  lab/.initial=,
}
\tikzset{pics/triangloid regular/.style={code={%
    \tikzset{triangloid regular/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangloid regular/##1}}%
    \draw[thick, pic actions] (-30:\pv{radius}) \foreach \x in {90,210}%
        {
            -- (\x:\pv{radius})}%
            -- cycle (90:\pv{radius})%
            (0,\pv{radius}) coordinate node[above, scale=2.5] {\pv{lab}}%
            ;
        }
    },
}

\tikzset{squaroid regular/.cd,
  radius/.initial=3cm,
  lab/.initial=,
}

\tikzset{pics/squaroid regular/.style={code={%
    \tikzset{squaroid regular/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/squaroid regular/##1}}
    \draw[thick, pic actions] (45:\pv{radius}) \foreach \x in {135,225,...,359}
        {
            -- (\x:\pv{radius})}%
            -- cycle (90:\pv{radius})%
            (0,\pv{radius}) coordinate node[above, scale=2.5] {\pv{lab}}
            ;
        }
    },
}
\tikzset{
  pentagoid regular/.cd,
  radius/.initial=3cm,
  lab/.initial=,
}

\tikzset{pics/pentagoid regular/.style={code={%
    \tikzset{pentagoid regular/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pentagoid regular/##1}}
    \draw[thick, pic actions] (18:\pv{radius}) \foreach \x in {90,162,...,359}
        {
            -- (\x:\pv{radius})}%
            -- cycle (90:\pv{radius})%
            (0,\pv{radius}) coordinate node[above, scale=2.5] {\pv{lab}}
            ;
        }
    },
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Radius of regular polygons
\newdimen\R
\R=2cm

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\sansmath\sffamily},thick, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm]

% Indicate the boundary of the regular polygons
\pic {triangloid regular={lab=Triangle}};
\pic[xshift=7cm] {squaroid regular={lab=Square}};
\pic[yshift=-7cm] {pentagoid regular={lab=Pentagone}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with output:

[image]

Comment: didn't hear about the polar coordinates. I'm currently looking into it.

Answer (score 3):

While you are waiting for the TikZ debugging service (which is frankly beyond me), here is a version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) purely for comparison.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
string name[];
name[3] = "Triangle";
name[4] = "Square";
name[5] = "Pentagon";
name[6] = "Hexagon";
name[7] = "Heptagon";
name[8] = "Octagon";
vardef polygon(expr n, r) =
    for i=0 upto n-1: up scaled r rotated (360/n*i) -- endfor cycle
enddef;
beginfig(1);
    for i=3 upto 8:
        path p;
        p = polygon(i, 60) shifted -144 (i mod 2, floor ((i-1)/2));
        fill p withcolor 7/8[blue, white];
        draw p;
        label.top(name[i], point 0 of p);
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so please compile it with `lualatex`.

Comment: thx. I have to talk to my boss about switching to LuaLaTeX >-<

Answer (score 2):

The `shapes.geometric` library has these polygons built in.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 3] in 
    {Triangle,Square,Pentagon,Hexagon,Heptagon,Octagon,Nonagon,Decagon}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{2.5*Mod(\Y-1,2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{-3*int((\Y-3)/2)}
    \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Y,draw,
        minimum size=2cm,label=below:\X] at (\myx,\myy){};
         }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]